# Monitor USB port without physically plugin hard drive

Tags: vps, usb, port, shell-scripting

I have to design a program to monitor USB ports of a linux server to detect when an external hard drive is plugged in and removed.

Now I have one confusion in my mind about it. I have my own VPS. so if i design a program then how can i check it without physically plugging external drive as i'm working on vps. does it mean that there is no other way except that I install OS on my own computer at home and then plugin hard drive myself and check it?

actually I have to develop this program for 3 different OS thats why I'm asking.

Comment: Does your VPS software allow you to connect and disconnect USB devices from servers? If so, no problem. Otherwise, you'll need to use a physical machine to test.

Comment: No. VPS doesn't provide this kind of services.

Comment: Then either switch VPS software or use a physical machine.

Comment: what if i install vmware on my windows and then try it? i have never played with vmware so don't know about it. what do you suggest. can it work?

Comment: Yes, it works with Vmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would check it on a physical machine.

It's not a high cost and you will be assured that it actually works properly.